# Problem with my website carousel / React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel

I have a problem with my website output.
I use the carousel to show my skills and I fetch data from Sanity.

My code: https://github.com/Izabela88/my-portfolio/blob/components/src/components/UI/Carousel/Carousel.js

My problem is that after loading the page, the content of the carousel is not displayed, I can only see the arrows(buttons), but when I press any of the buttons everything is displayed correctly.

What should I change in the code so that the carousel's contents show up when the page is loaded?

Comment: You declared the `sliders` out of the component, so every time you change the value, the component doesn't know if needs to render... I think you can use the slidesReducer to store the 'sliders' value

Comment: Hi:) thank you for your answer. Do you have any idea how I could store it?

Comment: You need to create a new 'if' inside the slidesReducer.. and other things. I wrote this code that you can see where you should change https://jsfiddle.net/tx28L73y/3/    but, As I don't have your project running, I am not sure that will work.. maybe needs more changes. But I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still have information on the console: 'slides' is not defined.

Comment: Do you know what line it is referring to?. I also fixed a typo.. please, could you check this code again - https://jsfiddle.net/x26bwqcu/  (I've updated)

Comment: Yes I updated this before and the errors are: src\components\UI\Carousel\Carousel.js
  Line 65:44:   'slides' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 72:34:   'slides' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 148:22:  'slides' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 161:13:  'slides' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure.. maybe you are trying access the variable `slides` without declare it. But now, all information of slides it will be inside the `state.slides`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will leave it for now and go on, maybe something will come to my mind later:)

Comment: No problem. If you want I can clone your project and test in my computer. Which branch are you working?

Comment: Really? Would be great!:) I'm currently working on a component branch and I didn't push it to development branch yet. https://github.com/Izabela88/my-portfolio/tree/components

Comment: Yes, sure. I just did it. You can check in your repository - https://github.com/Izabela88/my-portfolio/pull/3/files. I hope that can help you. Let me know if there's any error.